# How was Abd al-Rahman I recognized when he arrived in Islamic Hispania?

Tags: middle-ages, islam, umayyad-caliphate, caliphate, islamic-hispania

[Abd al-Rahman I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abd-ar-Rahman_I) was the founder of the Umayyad dynasty in Hispania, and he was one of the last Umayyad survivors when the Abbasid overthrew the Umayyad caliphate in Damascus. According to what I read, he fled Damascus, travelled west on low profile, and finally arrived in Hispania after 6 years missing. In Hispania he quickly amassed support, defeated the local Muslim ruler and installed himself as Emir. According to Wikipedia:

> Abd-ar-Rahman I became Emir of Córdoba in 756; fleeing for six years
>   after the Umayyads had lost the position of Caliph held in Damascus in
>   750. Intent on regaining a position of power, he defeated the existing Islamic rulers of the area who defied Umayyad rule and united various
>   local fiefdoms into an emirate.

I'm curious how the people in Hispania verified that he was in fact Abd al-Rahman, the Umayyad prince, because:

- He travelled on low profile, so I guess this also mean without strong
  troops or obvious indicator of being a royal
- Hispania was pretty far from Damascus, so probably Hispanic peoples have less idea about how Umayyad princes look or how to verify them
- He didn't seem to be an important prince, like the heir to the throne, he just happened to be one of the survivor.
- Yet enough people in Hispania believed him to allow him to take over.

Comment: This could possibly be expanded to a question of how people would prove their identity in the Caliphate in general.

Comment: Excellent question! Perhaps he had some family relics or something?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg Even if he did, how did people from Spain verify relics from a ruling family previously based in Damascus?

Comment: I'd like to start a bounty on this, but I can't, because I'll end up rewarding the existing "answer", even though it does in fact not answer the question at all. Annoying.

Comment: @LennartRegebro AFAIK you can "just assign a bounty to a specific answer", unless they have changed everything again...

Comment: @Lohoris: But that assumes I get new answers. :-I But it turns out it's OK, existing answers doesn't get the bounty unless I specifically assign it.

Comment: @LennartRegebro oh ok, I assumed you posted the bounty before Mario Elocio's answer. You didn't comment it, is there a reason why it does not satisfy you? I'd like to know!

Comment: @Lohoris: I also posted the *comment* before his answer. You seem confused, but I don't know about what.

Comment: One correction tho, while Umayyads did not follow the European Agnatic-Primogeniture law (Which means eldest son or eldest child of the eldest son inherits), Abdul Rahman was eldest son of Prince Muawiya who was himself the eldest son of Caliph/Emperor Hisham II. So that makes Abdul Rahman very likely to have inherited the throne at some point in his life if the Dynasty was not deposed.

Answer (score 10):

*Peter C. Scales:The Fall of the Caliphate of Cordoba: Berbers and Andalusis in Conflict (Medieval Iberian Peninsula, Vol 9)*, the source linked in the answer by
@Mr.lock / @Kobunite

actually hints at *a plausible answer* to OP's question, namely that

- *Abd al-Rahman was recognized when he arrived in al-Andalus because members of the Umayyad family had already established themselves
  there*.

Relaying accounts by Muslim historians Scales says (**[p112](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=m-Wvg__iHPAC&lpg=PA239&vq=Rahman&pg=PA111#v=onepage&q=739&f=false)**) that already in **121AH/739AD**
some 30,000 soldiers, among them 10,000 Umayyads, had been sent westwards by Calpih Hisham.

A vanguard of this detachment, *some 7,000 Umayyads*, found themselves besieged by Berbers in **Ceuta**, and appealed to the governor of al-Andalus to be allowed to cross the Gibraltar.

As he agreed these 7,000 would become the second wave of Arabs to settle in Spain.

So when **Abd al-Rahman** landed in al-Andalus 755AD he would be able to count on the **support from his own kin**.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, Abd al-Rahman were born in 731, so if those people had met with him before, it must have been when he'd been 8 years old or younger. Do you think they could recognize him in 755?

Comment: @Fitri He might have been accompanied by older family members known to the kinfolk; if I'm not mistaken the grandfather of Abd al-Rahman was the same Caliph who sent these people westwards in the 730's.

Answer (score 2):

Abd al-Rahman I's mother was a [Moor from a tribe called Nafra](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=m-Wvg__iHPAC&lpg=PA239&vq=Rahman&pg=PA111#v=onepage&q&f=false) (click the link for pg 111). That helped him to be recognized first in Morocco and then in Islamic Spain as well.

Comment: Actually, this answer makes a very good point. I don't see why people downvoted it (the form is a bit messy but the substance is good!).

Comment: I agree, but it would be good if there were some sources quoted to verify it.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg: aside from the poor copyediting, there is no reference and it does not adequately explain why having a mother from tribe Nafra help the son to be recognized in Morocco and Spain.

Comment: @Louis Rhys - Just so I can learn and improve may I ask why the copy editing is poor?

Comment: @Kobunite I was referring to the version before your edit, with bad grammar, punctuation and capitalization. Now it doesn't look so bad.

Comment: @Louis Rhys Ah, fair enough. TY.

Comment: Found a reference, but my Google-book-fu isn't strong enough to make a good link of it. I put it in with instructions. :-(

Comment: I, somehow, managed to link directly to page 111. It's stupidly difficult to link to specific pages on Google Books. :S Great find T.E.D! :-)

Comment: "That helped him to be recognized first in Morocco and then in Islamic Spain as well." - How? I don't think this answers the question at all.